# In command line I am using testdisk, but the file is not getting located?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, testdisk

I am trying to use *test disk* on my Ubuntu software version 16.04 using command line (`sudo apt-get install test disk`) and after typing the password it is giving `Unable to locate package test disk`. What should I do?

Comment: Do you mean testdisk? https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/testdisk

Answer (score 1):

The package is called `testdisk` not `test disk`.
Before you first install software, you might need to update software list from the repositories.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install testdisk
```

Comment: i did use the testdisk like dis only its that dis website gives red lines for this spelling

Comment: if it's a fresh install or from live usb, you might need to update repositories before installation. Check my edit.

Comment: This site didn't give you the red lines suggesting that the word was misspelled; your browser, i.e. Firefox or Chromium, gave it to you. In matters Ubuntu, they are often wrong.